# Delete records in Visualforce page data table

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I created a Visualforce page with the following controller extension:

```
public class StudentsControllerExt {

public student__c NewStudent {get; set;}

public StudentsControllerExt (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
    this.NewStudent = new student__c();
}

public PageReference saveNewStudent(){
    insert NewStudent;
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(ApexPages.currentPage().getUrl());
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
 }
}
```

My Visualforce page adds records to custom object:

```
<apex:page StandardController="student__c" recordSetVar="students" extensions="StudentsControllerExt">


        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!students}" var="student">

            <apex:column value="{! student.name__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{! student.lastname__c }"/>     
            <apex:column value="{! student.university__c }"/>        
            <apex:column value="{! student.class__c }"/>
            <apex:column value="{! student.yob__c }"/>
            <apex:column value="{! student.address__c }" />

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>
```

My question is, how could I add a delete button to every row of the table that would remove the record from the table and database? I'm also wondering if it's possible to add an edit button that allows to make changes to records on the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to Add Edit/Delete link in your Page block table. Find the sample below.

You can find that I have added the links and using `apex:param` to pass the parameter. If you are planning to use this code in Lightning experience then you need to handle the redirect part.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="DataTableEditRemoveController">
<apex:form id="form" >
<apex:pageBlock title="Accounts">
<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accs}" var="row">
<apex:column >
<apex:outputLink title="" value="/{!row.id}/e?retURL=/apex/{!$CurrentPage.Name}" style="font-weight:bold">Edit</apex:outputLink>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="javascript&colon;if (window.confirm('Are you sure?')) DeleteAccount('{!row.Id}');" style="font-weight:bold">Del</a>
</apex:column>
<apex:column value="{!row.Name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!row.BillingStreet}"/>
<apex:column value="{!row.BillingCity}"/>
<apex:column value="{!row.BillingPostalCode}"/>
<apex:column value="{!row.BillingCountry}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:actionFunction action="{!DeleteAccount}" name="DeleteAccount" reRender="form" >
<apex:param name="accountid" value="" assignTo="{!SelectedAccountId}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Class

```
public class DataTableEditRemoveController {

public List<Account> accs { get; set; }

//used to get a hold of the account record selected for deletion
public string SelectedAccountId { get; set; }

public DataTableEditRemoveController() {
//load account data into our DataTable
LoadData();
}

private void LoadData() {
accs = [Select id, name, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingPostalCode, BillingCountry from Account limit 20];
}

public void DeleteAccount()
{
// if for any reason we are missing the reference
if (SelectedAccountId == null) {

return;
}

// find the account record within the collection
Account tobeDeleted = null;
for(Account a : accs)
if (a.Id == SelectedAccountId) {
tobeDeleted = a;
break;
}

//if account record found delete it
if (tobeDeleted != null) {
Delete tobeDeleted;
}

//refresh the data
LoadData();
}


}
```